# Ищу необходимую библиотеку для web-приложения

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, веб-программирование

Добрый день, я начинающий программист, выполняю работу в учебное заведение. Необходимо реализовать АСТ(автоматизированная система тестирования) "Тест Ландольта" в виде web-приложения. За backend взял ASP.Net MVC5. Для реализации самого теста необходимо реализовать Таймер на странице и порядка 1.5 тысячи элементов(кольца Ландольта). Была идея через JS создать элементы и реализовать логику проверки правильности выбора колец, но думаю, что это нагрузит страницу и ПК клиента, а хочется производительности) Можно использовать какую-то даже игровую библиотеку с 2D реализацией. Сам вопрос в том, какие вы посоветуете мне библиотеки и буду очень благодарен, если дадите ссылку на примеры. Неплохо будет если в них есть возможность адаптивность под размер экрана.
Про Three.js и pixi.js слышал, первая не устраивает, что там 3D, а для pixi.js не нашел доступных для меня примеров.Сами спрайты для колец уже реализованы.

Простите за столь длинный текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы на вашем месте посмотрел в сторону [D3.js](https://d3js.org/). Примеров море. Лучше даже посмотреть курсы по ней на [Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/). Смысла особенно перекладывать логику работы на сервер нет. Во-первых, в Вашем случае, важна динамика и отзывчивость на клиенте, следовательно на бэкэнде правильнее будет реализовать только логику анализа результатов, их хранеия и т.п. Современные браузеры высокопроизводительны, а js - язык со сборщиком мусора, так что, если основательно подойдёте к изучению библиотеки и основ js, всё должно получиться.

Comment: да, анализ результатов так и предполагалось проводить на стороне сервера. Спасибо большое за ответ, посмотрю, пощупаю так сказать. За ссылки отдельное спасибо)